# What parts do I need to change to convert from flat handle bar to drop bar?

Tags: handlebars

I am thinking about getting a drop bar for my Merida Speeder 200 (2015). But I am told that I need to change some other parts as well.

My bike has V type brakes, 3 speed front derailleur and a 9 speed Tiagra read derailleur.

Which shifter-brake lever(I mean road bike type shifter) is compatible with my bike I don't know. Also do I need a modification on brake system? Do I need to change any other parts? Most importantly, what would the cost be?

Can you help me?

Comment: If you look under "related" at right, you will find several copies of the same question.

Comment: A front "triple" is relatively uncommon but they do exist.  Good news is they're not an indexed item so all you need is the right mount and top vs bottom pull, where the cable aproaches the FD mech from.  It doesn't have to be the same groupset as anything else - FDs are the most brute-force part of the system cos they're working on the tensioned part of the chain.

Comment: Before committing to this significant change, I suggest you borrow a bike with drop bars and try riding it for a while.  See how it fits you.  For urban riding and commuting a flat bar seems better, a drop bar is for speed and aero and racing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it best, You will need the bar (obviously) and the brifter(brake/shifter) and to switch to cantilever brakes. The latter is avoidable if you use what's called a travel agent but if you have the money the canti's are the way to go, as the travel agents are ugly and I have heard a lot of people having issues with them.

The reason for this is that V brakes have a different pull ratio than road brakes and with v brakes and a road lever you don't get proper leverage and the result is poor braking.

Look up 9sp brifter on google and you should have a plethora of choices. You should be able to use your existing stem as long as the clamp diameter is the same.

If I had to guess your looking at a 200 bucks if your were to go through a shop, total guess on my part though, and that number could vary greatly dependent on the components and quality/brands you go with.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I should get a whole goup set because google says road bike shifters for 3 speed front derailleur is quite uncommon and of course expensive because mostly 2 speed derailleurs are used.

Comment: In my opinion it will come down to your budget and how often you will use the bike. 3 x 9 road shifters are a bit of a rarity but they do exist. SunRace makes some # STR81.83SS.BS0.BX Shimano also makes a 105 in a 3 x 9. looking online the 105's are about $150, Sunrace should be a little under that

Comment: Microshift r9 and 10-speed Campagnolo with so-called hubbub cable routing are options.

Comment: Can I combine different shifters? For example a 9 speed claris shifter and a 3 speed 105?

Comment: I don't see why not, may look a little odd though.